# Plot columns according to variables in R

Tags: r, function, plot

So I have to plot and save graphs for 100 items. 
Thus I wrote a function to plot these, and used variable to express the columns.
Like this:

```
plot <- function(a){
colname <- paste(a,"plot",sep="_")
plot_dat <- all_dat[,c(x,colname)]
plot(plot_dat$x, plot_dat$colname)
}
```

Like this, but the `plot_dat$colname` will always return `NULL` value, when actually they have values.

And then I can only plot the x value.

If I use

```
plot(plot_dat$x,colname)
```

instead, it always say,

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here is you are calling plot_dat$colname in a wrong fashion.
While plot_dat$x (since x is the original name of dataframe) is correct,
colname is a string, and plot_dat$colname will not call your column properly.

Solution 1 : 
 `plot(plot_dat$x, plot_dat[, colname])`

Solution 2 : 
 `plot(plot_dat[, c(x, colname)])`